# How do I add a new Currency to java.util.Currency for an existing country code in Java 7?

Tags: java, jvm, currency, java-7

For example, the Chinese currency has the `ISO 4217` code `CNY`. Since free global trading in that currency is restricted though, there's a second 'offshore' currency equivalent, called `CNH`. Wikipedia has a bit of [summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renminbi#CNH) of this all.

In `Java 7`, there's a [method for updating](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.7.html#currency) the set of three letter `ISO 4217` codes that the JVM ships with.  However, it can't be used to add a separate currency code to an existing country code: it would replace `CNY` with `CNH`, which is no good for my purposes.

How do I add `CNH` (which is not in the `ISO 4217` list) to the set of available currencies in `Java 7`, without overwriting `CNY`?

Put another way, how can I get multiple currency codes for a single country?

Note that this question: [How do I add the new currency code to Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982537/how-do-i-add-the-new-currency-code-to-java) was *asked and answered* for **Java 6**.  But the strategy of replacing `java.util.CurrencyData` doesn't work because that file no longer exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add the new currency code to Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982537/how-do-i-add-the-new-currency-code-to-java)

Comment: @bobs The method for doing this in Java 6 vs Java 7.  The question you linked to is Java 6, this is Java 7.

Comment: @bobs I know...  I asked both of them!  ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key here is in a [change that's part of Java 7](https://blogs.oracle.com/naotoj/entry/currency_enhancements_in_jdk71) to allow updating of the list of currencies without rebuilding rt.jar by replacing a file called `currency.data`.  Using this approach, rather than the `currency.properties` override approach, allows you to add new Currency codes without affecting other ones from the same country.

What's left unsaid there is how to go about actually building a new `currency.data`.
This file is generated from a file called `CurrencyData.properties`, which can be found in the OpenJDK source code in java/util.

What I did was copy the `CurrencyData.properties` found in the [OpenJDK source](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/) (`openjdk\jdk\src\share\classes\java\util`), and changed the line:

```
BZD084-CAD124-CDF976-CHF756-CLF990-CLP152-CNY156-COP170-CRC188-CSD891-CUP192-\
```

to

```
BZD084-CAD124-CDF976-CHF756-CLF990-CLP152-CNH156-CNY156-COP170-CRC188-CSD891-CUP192-\
```

Then I grabbed the `GenerateCurrencyData.java` file in the source distribution at `openjdk\jdk\make\tools\src\build\tools\generatecurrencydata`.  This utility takes input from System.In in the same format as CurrencyData.properties, and turns it in to a currency.data file.  I made a slight change so that it used a FileInputStream instead of System.In:

```
currencyData.load(System.in);
```

to

```
currencyData.load(new FileInputStream(fileName));
```

Run that on your edited CurrencyData.properties file and, after putting the original .data file somewhere safe, place the resulting currency.data file in to your JRE\lib directory, and you can now run code that uses `Currency.getInstance("CNH")`.

Answer (score 0):

To the @sharakan answer:
You may also need to add newly changed currency, in my case BYN

BY=BYR;2016-07-01-00-00-00;BYN

in format:
OLD_CUR;DATE_OF_CHANGE;NEW_CUR

Hope it will help someone.