# Implementing Bitcoin and java.util.Currency

Tags: java, java-7, currency, bitcoin

I'm trying to add bitcoin as a currency to display on my site.  I've got exchange rates and everything, but I keep getting an `IllegalArgumentException` whenever I use `java.util.Currency.getInstance("BTC")`.  This makes sense since it's not included in the list of [ISO 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Without_currency_code) currency codes, and also not in Java 7.  I've seen a couple of options, but nothing that really solves my issue.

1. According to the Java [platform docs](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html), you can override a specific locale's currency by creating a file `$JAVA_HOME/lib/currency.properties`.  This is a problem since bitcoin is not tied to a specific locale, nor should it be used in place of any country's currency.
2. Another similar situation was presented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432527/how-do-i-add-a-new-currency-to-java-util-currency-for-an-existing-country-code-i) StackOverflow post, where China had a second currency code to be used, so the solution was to build your own `currency.data` file that added a second currency for the China locale.  This is better, but there is still the issue of tying a currency to a locale.

Has anyone run into this problem or found a workaround? I know bitcoin is relatively new, but it'd be cool to be able to display prices in bitcoin format.

Comment: Do you *have to* use java.util.Currency? You could just use String or write your own class instead.

Comment: In a word, yes. This application is huge and this wasn't supposed to be a major change, so building a new class isn't worth it at this point.  Now if we actually started accepting bitcoin payments or something then maybe this would be necessary.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, hacking it with reflection is one way :)

Comment: @aditsu Hacking with reflection is unnecessary! See my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use BTC as the currency code for bitcoins under [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Code_formation). [BT is reserved](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/iso-3166-1_decoding_table.htm#BT) for Bhutan. However, ISO 3166-1 [reserves several country codes](http://www.iso.org/iso/special-code-elements-iso-3166.htm#User_assigned_code_elements) for user definition. Additionally, the wiki for [ISO 4217 lists `XBT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Without_currency_code) as a currency code for bitcoins (unofficially, of course).

```
Locale.Builder b = new Locale.Builder();
b.setRegion("XB");
Locale xb = b.build();
Currency bitcoin = Currency.getInstance(xb);
```

Your `currency.properties` file will look like:

```
XB=XBT,000,3
```

Unfortunately, you cannot have [8 for the minor unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin) because the parsing for [`java.util.Currency`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Currency.java#230) only handles a minor unit of `0-3`:

```
Pattern propertiesPattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]{3})\\s*,\\s*(\\d{3})\\s*,\\s*([0-3])");
```

Comment: Interesting, I will look into this.  We're probably going to shelve it for now, but thanks for this!

Comment: Alright, I've tried your method but I can't seem to get it to pull from `currency.properties`.  I even tried replacing Bhutan's currency just to see if it would work.  Is there some cache I need to clear or something?

Comment: @tedski Not that I know of. Are you placing the file in the correct location? Try doing `System.println(System.getProperty("java.home"))` to see where `$JAVA_HOME` is. (You might have multiple JVMs installed on your computer or if you're using the JDK it might be using the `jre` folder as its home.)

Comment: That was it, I had it in the wrong `/lib` folder.  Ended up being `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib`.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Jeffrey , do you know if there's any way to pass the `XB=XBT,000,3` as a -D flag instead of that properties file?

Comment: @tedski I don't know. You could try making your own [`LocaleServiceProvider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html) and going from there, but I don't see anything about passing it as a D flag.

Comment: Caveat: the first 2 chars of the currency code must be equal to country code